# Unable to get data into correct format after web scraping in python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

i have written a code that scrapes the websites: https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=GTX&bop=And&Page=
    {}&PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH".format(page)

but when i run this code, data is not formtted, like product name is coming in ever cell and so on price and image.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("Scrapedetails.csv", "w")
Headers = "Item_Name, Price, Image\n"
f.write(Headers)

for page in range(1,15):
    page_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?
Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=GTX&bop=And&Page=
{}&PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH".format(page)
    html = urlopen(page_url)
    bs0bj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    page_details = bs0bj.find_all("div", {"class":"item-container"})
    for i in page_details:
         Item_Name = i.find("a", {"class":"item-title"})
         Price = i.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
         Image = i.find("img")
         Name_item = Item_Name.get_text()
         Prin = Price.get_text()
         imgf = Image["src"]# to get the key src 
         f.write("{}".format(Name_item).strip()+ ",{}".format(Prin).strip()+ 
  ",{}".format(imgf)+ "\n")
f.close()
```

can someone help me to ammend codes so that i can get name in name column, price in price column and image in image column.
what are the new ways to save data in csv,can someone help me in it with codes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i got it solved.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("Scrapedetails.csv", "w")
Headers = "Item_Name, Price, Image\n"
f.write(Headers)

for page in range(1,15):
    page_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?
Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=GTX&bop=And&Page=
{}&PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH".format(page)
    html = urlopen(page_url)
    bs0bj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    page_details = bs0bj.find_all("div", {"class":"item-container"})
    for i in page_details:
        Item_Name = i.find("a", {"class":"item-title"})
        Price = i.find("li", {"class":"price-current"}).find('strong')
        Image = i.find("img")
        Name_item = Item_Name.get_text().strip()
        prin = Price.get_text()
        imgf = Image["src"]# to get the key src 


        print(Name_item)
        print(prin)
        print('https:{}'.format(imgf))
        f.write("{}".format(Name_item).replace(",", "|")+ ",{}".format(prin)+ ",https:{}".format(imgf)+ "\n")
f.close()
```

These are the codes for anyone who wishes to start with webscraping a simplest way